# Spin of an ensemble of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

In Zwiebach, [Mastering Quantum Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026204613X), Chapter 1, we consider an ensemble of electrons in the following state:
$$|\Psi\rangle=|\uparrow;z\rangle+|\downarrow;z\rangle$$
It is said that with this ensemble, a measurement of the spin along the $x$ axis would result in all spins pointing up along the $x$ axis. Where can I find the calculations that would show that?

Comment: Hint: find the eigenstates of $\sigma_x$.

Comment: Once I have those though, I'll have to do more calculations with $|\psi\rangle$ as input to finally find that I get one of the 2 eigenstates exclusively, right?

Comment: Once you have this all will be revealed…. The only way to always get the same outcome if is the state is an eigenstate of the appropriate observable.

Comment: Just apply $S_x|\Psi\rangle$, you will see it is an eigenstate. What does the Born rule says about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to project on to the corresponding eigenvector, namely, the eigenvector of the spin-x operator along the up direction,  $$|\uparrow; x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow; z\rangle+|\downarrow; z\rangle.$$ Then, by the postulates of quantum mechanics, $$P(\uparrow; x)=|\langle \uparrow; x|\psi\rangle|^2.$$ Note that the state you provide is not normalized yet; the normalized state is $$|\psi\rangle=|\uparrow; x\rangle.$$ In that case the square amplitude is one, as stated.